# Node.js middleware wrap

Tags: node.js, async-await, handler, wrapper, middleware

I am trying to write my own node.js server, so far I have a question.

```
const asyncHandler = (fn) => async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (!fn) next();
        await fn(req, res, next);
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
}

const errorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
    if (!error.code) {
        error = new InternalServerError(error.message ? error.message : 'Something broke');
    }
    const errorResponse = new MessageResponse(error.code, error.message);
    res.status(errorResponse.code).send(errorResponse.body);
}
```

These are two middlewares, the first one handles promise rejection the second one is express error handler.
I am using first one like this

```
router.get('/', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let tasks = await TaskService.getAllTasks();
    tasks = tasks.map(task => {
        return task.entitize();
    })
}));
```

So I need to wrap all route middleware function into an async handler to handle the rejection. But what if I had 10000 route middleware functions? Can I write some code to wrap all route middleware functions into this async handler BY DEFAULT? I mean writing like this

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    throw new Error('aaa');
    let tasks = await TaskService.getAllTasks();
    tasks = tasks.map(task => {
        return task.entitize();
    })
});
```

And this middleware is wrapped by asyncHandler? Has anyone done it before? Are there any libs I can use to achieve this? 
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the original `router.get` function and do your async/error handling stuff there along with delegating to the original function. Something like this should work:

```
const router = express.Router();    
const _route = router.route.bind(router);
const methodsToWrap = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete'];

router.route = function(path) {
  const route = _route(path);
  for (const method of methodsToWrap) {
    if (route[method]) {
      route[method] = wrap(route[method]);
    }
  }
  return route;
};

function wrap(originRouterMethod) {
  return function() {
    const originMiddlewares = [...arguments];
    const wrappedMiddlewares = originMiddlewares.map(fn => {
      if (typeof fn !== `function`) {
        return fn;
      }

      return async function(req, res, next) {
        try {
          await fn.apply(null, arguments);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Caught error ' + err);
          next(err);
        }
      };
    });
    originRouterMethod.call(this, wrappedMiddlewares);
  };
}
```

With that you don't need to add `asyncHandler` to all your routes in your setup, you can just specify them as:

```
...
router.get('/', async(req, res, next) => {
    let tasks = await TaskService.getAllTasks();
    tasks = tasks.map(task => {
            return task.entitize();
        });
});
...
```

Comment: Thx, will try this as soon as possible.

Comment: It worked for get, but how can I do for all possible request methods(get,post,patch,delete)?

Comment: Just go over all properties of the route-object and wrap if the key matches -> I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks, that's a very complex and awesome solution, helped me a lot. <3

Comment: adding `return originRouterMethod.call(this, wrappedMiddlewares);` will make this able to chain methods, which is supported by original router